# How to use SDL2 on OS X via Makefile?

Tags: terminal, homebrew, gcc

I have homebrew and its sdl2 package properly installed on OS X El Capitan, and the SDL2 headers are in /usr/local/include/SDL2, but when I use -lSDL2 in gcc and `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` as in Linux, I get the error `fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found`
Why is this happening? Should I symlink /usr/local/include to /usr/include/?

Comment: Did you add `export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib"` to your `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: You probably need `-I/usr/local/include` in CFLAGS. Also/instead, try adding `$(sdl2-config --cflags --libs)` to your compile command. See [Installation - SDL Wiki](http://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation)

Comment: @jherran: I didn't, I wasn't ware I had to do that in OS X.

Comment: @mtklr: That seems kind of strange, why do you have to do these in OS X?

Comment: Because is what this brew package docs says. Doing that you probably not needing the -I option on gcc command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`

```
gcc -I /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -framework SDL2 your_file.c
```

the framework has to be in your list of library paths to be searched